# printing in java through barcode printer fit to scale

Tags: java, printing, java-print

I am trying to print barcode image files using java. I have Label Writer 450 Turbo. The label dimension is 2" X 0.75" inches, When I print the image from Photoshop with scale to fit option every thing works fine.

[image: The barcode example]

But with java code it does not scale the image in right way, so the barcode reader cannot read it anymore.

```
public class print {

    public static void main(String[] str) {
        // Input the file
        FileInputStream textStream = null;
        try {
            textStream = new FileInputStream("barcode.jpg");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exp) {
            return;
        }

        DocFlavor myFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG;
        PageFormat format = new PageFormat();
        format.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);

        Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(textStream, myFormat, null);
        // Build a set of attributes
        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        // aset.add(new Copies(2));
        aset.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0, 0, 0.75f, 2f,
                MediaPrintableArea.INCH));
        aset.add(PrintQuality.HIGH);

        aset.add(new PrinterResolution(300, 600, PrinterResolution.DPI));
        aset.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);

        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(
                myFormat, null);

        if (services.length > 0) {
            DocPrintJob job = services[5].createPrintJob();

            for (Attribute temp : services[5].getAttributes().toArray())
                System.out.println(temp.getName());

            try {
                job.print(myDoc, aset);
            } catch (PrintException pe) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The barcode generated using krysalis barcode4j using the following settings

```
resolution -> 600
line height -> 15.35mm
```

**Edit One:**  here is example of the two printed labels one using Photoshop with scale to fit option, and the other using java code

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? If so, please kindly share. Now I'm getting trouble with that.

Comment: No I didn't find a solution I generated them using java and printed using adobe.